# Databricks: Python pivot table in spark dataframe

Tags: python, databricks

Anyone can give me some guidance on the pivot table, using spark dataframe in python language 
I am getting the following error :Column is not iterable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4zKq.jpg)

anyone has idea ?

Comment: Not sure of the Seq. You may need a filter I suspect.

Answer (score 1):

Pivots function Pivots a column of the current DataFrame and performs the specified aggregation operation. There are two versions of pivot function: one that requires the caller to specify the list of distinct values to pivot on, and one that does not.

1. With specifying column values - df.groupBy("year").pivot("course", Seq("dotNET", "Java")).sum("earnings")
2. without specifying column values (more concise but less efficient) - df.groupBy("year").pivot("course").sum("earnings")

You are proceeding in the right direction. Sample working code, python 2

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
>>> spark = SparkSession.builder.master('local').appName('app').getOrCreate()
>>> df = spark.read.option('header', 'true').csv('pivot.csv')
>>> df = df.withColumn('value1', col('value1').cast("int"))
>>> pdf = df.groupBy('thisyear').pivot('month', ['JAN','FEB']).sum('value1')
>>> pdf.show(10)
+--------+---+---+
|thisyear|JAN|FEB|
+--------+---+---+
|    2019|  3|  2|
+--------+---+---+

//pivot.csv
thisyear,month,value1
2019,JAN,1
2019,JAN,1
2019,FEB,1
2019,JAN,1
2019,FEB,1
```